# Eloquent. How to get access to not related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following Models:

**Shop_list**

**Shopping_list_item**

**Product**

If I try to to use hasManyThrough (I made intentionally mistakes in `'shopping_list_idd'`, `'idd'` to display error message):

```
 public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Shopping_list_item::class, 'shopping_list_idd', 'idd', 'product_id');
    }
```

I get the following:

> SQL: select `products`.*, `shopping_list_items`.`shopping_list_idd`
>   from `products` inner join `shopping_list_items` on
>   **shopping_list_items.id**= `products`.`idd` where
>   `shopping_list_items`.`shopping_list_idd` is null limit 1

**Question:** how to change `shopping_list_items.id` to `shopping_list_items.product_id`, so I have correct join? Or maybe you have other suggestion how I can get access to `product` information from `shop_list`.

**Additional question:** why there is this part is null limit 1 at the end of the query?

Comment: Can you share the relevant table definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved here - [Has many through many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430217/has-many-through-many-to-many). Here there is relation Many to Many, so you can't just simply use `hasManyThrough`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to switch position from `'id', 'product_id'` to `'product_id','id'`

Comment: If I switch it doesn't change the id:
SQL: select `products`.*, `shopping_list_items`.`shopping_list_idd` from `products` inner join `shopping_list_items` on `shopping_list_items`.`id` = `products`.`product_id` where `shopping_list_items`.`shopping_list_idd` is null limit 1