# Laravel 5.4 hasManyThrough returns wrong query

Tags: php, laravel

i have in my `Seller` Model following relation

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Member::class, Organization::class, 'seller_id', 'organization_id', 'id');
}
```

Table Structure:

**sellers**

- id

**seller_organizations**

- seller_id
- organization_id

**organizations**

- id

**organization_members**

- id
- organization_id

A Seller has many organizations and an organization has many members.

In my Seller\MemberController i want to parse the query like

```
 private function parseRequest(Request $request, Seller $seller)
    {
        $query = $seller->organizationMembers();
}
```

Response:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'organizations.seller_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `organization_members` inner join `organizations` on `organizations`.`id` = `organization_members`.`organization_id` where `organizations`.`seller_id` = 123)

How can i tell laravel that it needs to look in seller_organizations table for the correct relation?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your peculiar case is different from the generic solution Laravel provides out of the box. Create a `belongsToMany` relationship on the `Seller` model for `organizations` 
 like this:

```
public function organizations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class, 'seller_organizations', 'seller_id', 'organization_id');
    }
```

On the `organization` model, add a `hasMany` `members` relationship like this:

```
public function organizationMembers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrganizationMember::class);
    }
```

Then finally in the `Seller` model, add the `members` relationship as follows:

```
public function members()
    {
        $members= new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

        foreach($this->organizations as $organization)
        {
            $members = $members->merge($organization->organizationMembers->get());
        }

        return $members->unique();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. this in comination with this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324793/7226875] (answer) from  @Namoshek did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a function with a simple query like this one:

```
class Seller
{
    public function organizationMembers()
    {
        return OrganizationMember::query()
            ->whereHas('organization', function ($query) {
                $query->whereHas('sellers', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('id', $this->id);
                });
            });
    }
}
```

But you will not be able to use a built-in relationship type. So eager loading will not be available for you in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Seller`s and `Organization`s make a many-to-many relationship, so in that case you couldn't apply the [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) because it is the union of two one-to-many relationship on the same direction, like this:

```
|A| has many |B|
|B| has many |c|
```

So, when doing the query it follows this logic:

```
|A| has many |C| through |B|.
```

You could define your own relationship tho, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37720428/7117697) answer. Just remember to change `->lists()` with `->pluck(...)`.