# Laravel 3 tables on belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Based on the official Laravel documentation I found that :

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

In this case, imagine we have a structure like this :

```
books
books_authors
authors
contacts
books_authors_contacts
```

That's just an hypotetic case but I would like some more information : what about if I would like to retrieve all authors contacts for this specific book, imagining that for a specific book multiples authors could have multiple contacts (such contacts are linked through both authors and books as the entity books_authors_contacts says)

Is it possible to retrieve it through Laravel with eager loading with a belongsToMany relation?

By using the example below, it would just retrieve all of the contacts of an author no matter the book is.

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is tricks to gain this functionality in a very complex fashion, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430217/has-many-through-many-to-many). In a more practical sense, when these cases arrive in a professional environment, you often end up doing a method that aggregates this data. This can be done in multiple ways, this is an approach i feel is fairly easy and readable.

```
public class Book
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        $contacts = new Collection();

        $this->authors->each(function(Author $author) use($contacts) {
            $contacts->concat($author->contacts);
        })

        return $contacts;
    }
}
```

Offcourse for the eager loading, you have to remember to include the whole structure. For more `Laravel` approach contacts can be made as a `Eloquent Mutator`.

```
$book = App\Book::with('authors.contacts')->find(1);
$contacts = $book->authors();
```