# HasManyThrough Through Several Related Tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to list a sum of related table with scenario like this:

Provinces --> Regencies --> Districts --> Villages --> Users.

I want to recap all regency, districts, villages and users on one time request through Province model.

I have created this relationship:

Province Model

```php
    public function regencies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Regency::class);
    }

    public function districts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            District::class,
            Regency::class,
            'province_id',
            'regency_id',
            'id',
            'id'
        );
    }

    public function villages()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Village::class,
            District::class,
            Regency::class,
            'province_id',
            'regency_id',
            'district_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'id'
        );
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            User::class,
            Village::class,
            District::class,
            Regency::class,
            'province_id',
            'regency_id',
            'district_id',
            'village_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'id'
        );
    }
```

Regency Model

```php
    public function districts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(District::class);
    }
```

District Model

```php
    public function villages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Village::class);
    }
```

Village Model

```php
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

User Model

```php
    public function village()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Village::class,'village_id');
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```php
    public function province(){
        $data = Province::whereHas('regencies',function($one){
            $one->whereHas('districts',function($two){
                $two->whereHas('villages', function($three){
                    $three->whereHas('users', function($four){
                    });
                });
            });
        })->get();
        return new GraphProvinceCollection(true, 'List of Data',$data);
    }
```

This is my GraphProvinceCollection:

```php
    public $success, $message;
    public function __construct($success, $message, $data)
    {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->success = $success;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'success'   => $this->success,
            'message'   => $this->message,
            'data'      => $this->collection->transform(function($val){
                return new GraphProvinceResource($val);
            })
        ];
    }
```

and This is my GraphProvinceResource:

```php
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'province'      => $this->name,
            'regencies'     => $this->regencies->count(),
            'districts'     => $this->districts->count(),
            'villages'      => $this->villages->count(),
            'users'         => $this->users->count(),
        ];
    }
```

This is my data:

[image: This is my data on Database]

I have execute the Eloquent, the province, regency, and district return right, but the village and user return false.
[image: This is my result when I execute the query]

How to solve this on Eloquent?

Thank you.

Comment: If you need all of the models then you can just eager-load them.
If not:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430217/has-many-through-many-to-many

Comment: I think your cases you show on comment is not suitable with my cases, your cases if being compared with my cases is only until level districts, it's deal/product --> deal_product --> metrics_product, it's only 3 levels, but in my cases it's provinces --> regencies --> districts --> villages --> users, it's 5 level. In my cases, for 3 level it's ok, you can see on district, it's shown well.