# Laravel relationship in three ways

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a rather unique relationship I'd like to define, but can't seem to find a name for this relationship.

My database structure is as follows:

- A `user`, filled with for this example irrelevant data
- A `user_organisation` table with `user_organisation.user_id` and `user_organisation.organisation_id`
- An `organisation`, filled with for this example irrelevant data
- An `event` containing a `event.organisation_id` key

I would like to define the relationship `user` -> `events`. Or in other words: all the events in the organisations that the user is part of.

Comment: Look up HasManyThrough

Comment: Thanks for responding, I thought of that as well. However, that attempts to look for a 'organisation.user_id' column, which does not exist because the user-organisation relationship is many.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430217/has-many-through-many-to-many

Comment: That does imitate the behaviour I'm looking for, but I'm really looking for a built-in Laravel solution, all the other ways of defining that 'relationship' break key functionality like `paginate`. It seems that Laravel simply doesn't support this relationship type, so I'm stuck with joining. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Use a custom defined function with query builder. You will have access to everything you normally would, but without a “relationship” wrapper

Answer (score 0):

In your User model :

```
public function organisations() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Organisation::model, 'user_organisation');
}
```

In your Organisation model :

```
public function users() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::model, 'user_organisation');
}

public function events() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Event::model);
}
```

In your Event model :

```
public function organisation() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::model);
}
```

Then :

```
$user = User::find(1);
$organisations = $user->organisations;
foreach($organisations as $organisation) { 
    $user_organisation_events = $organisation->events;
}
```

Or in your User model :

```
public function getAllEvents() { 
    $events = new Collection();
    $organisations = $this->organisations;
    foreach($organisations as $organisation) { 
        $events[] = $organisation->events();
    }
    return $events;
}
```

So that $user->getAllEvents() should return a collection of all the events for all the organisations they're association with.

EDIT:

In case you'd want to return an eloquent object instead of a collection, you could also add a method that looks like this:

```
public function events() { 
    $organisations = $this->organisations;
    return Event::query()->whereHas('organisations', function ($query) {
        $query->where('organisation_id', $organisations->pluck('organisation_id'));
    }); 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't allow me to call the usual relationship functions, like  `paginate()`. Is there no native Laravel relation that facillitates the behaviour I'm looking for?

Comment: See the edit made by @jschpmr which returns an eloquent object you should then be able to paginate.